# Unable to provide input for a selected attribute of a drop down list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public partial class Department
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Department()
        {
            this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsSelected { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    } 

    public ActionResult Create()
            {
                List<SelectListItem> DeptList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (Department tempdept in db.Departments)
                {
                    SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = tempdept.Name,
                        Value = tempdept.ID.ToString(),
                        Selected = tempdept.IsSelected.HasValue ? tempdept.IsSelected.Value : false
                    };
                    DeptList.Add(sli);
                }
                ViewBag.Departments = DeptList;
                return View();
            }


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentID, "DepartmentID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentID,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Departments,new { @class = "form-control" ,
                   @selected = ViewBag.Departments.Selected.HasValue && ViewBag.Departments.Selected.Value ? "selected" : null
               })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Above, I have mentioned the code for the model, the controller and then the view.
Basically, I was trying to set a default DropDownList Element by taking user input from the database using the IsSelected field in the Department table.
So if the `IsSelected` Column in the Database for the corresponding department has a `1` and all the others have a `NULL` or a `0`, then the department that has a `1` gets `selected` as the default element in the DropDownList when there is a `Get`.

But as soon as I run my code I am encountered with the error

> (''System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Selected'')

Unable to figure out such behavior.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: is it possible that multiple departments will have IsSelected value as 1?

Comment: I actually wanted to set the default element of the DropDownList through the IsSelected field.....Since there can be only one  default element hence only one department will be having the corresponding value of IsSelected as 1

Answer (score 1):

Remove ur @selected = html attribute in the @Html.DropDownListFor, the drop down is smart enough to set the selected from the SelectListItem

In my case i filled the viewBag with strings so i create the collection of SelectListItem in @Razer but can also be filled from the controller

this is working for me:

in the xxx.cshtml file

```
@{
    var weights = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.PossibleWeights)
    {
        weights.Add(
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = item,
            Value = item,
            Selected = item == Model.WeightCode
        });

    }
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WeightCode, weights, new { @class = "form-control")
```